# jQuery slider stop dynamically at end or append li items to continue

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to get a jQuery function to slide li items left and right by clicking an arrow. I am using a jQuery script called TinyCarousel.js. While I have it functioning properly, it continues to scroll right until the last li item is in the first position. What I have currently can be seen [here](http://mmo-aggro.com) in the "Games Currently Testing or Releasing section" under the main slider. If you scroll all the way to the right you will notice the issue.

Is it possible to either...

1) Change the jQuery to make the last li item stop once it is showing all the way on the right side of the window? I know this would have to be relative to the browser window size as well as make one single partial movement incase the window size has a partial item showing. I also know I would have to know the amount of li items which I can do within the php.

2) Or two, append the li continually so that the slider never seems to end. Just continues through repeating over and over? I would guess that I need to continually append li items as well as remove them if they are off screen.

I attempted to create a [jFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pelligea/82fdK/) to show the issue. But it is doing something all together different on jFiddle which is closer to what I need. It seems to stop moving right at some point. But it does not need the entire last li to display completely. What is it doing differently than what I have on the live site where it does stop?

Any help is greatly appreciated. I did search and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926939/tiny-carousel-plugin-autostop-at-last-slide) but it did not seem to work in this situation. Thank you in adavnce.

I have am using jQuery 1.10.2, php 5.4, TinyCarousel.js version 1.9

Here is what I have currently.
The CSS

```
.PrevArrow {
    width: 5%;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.NextArrow {
    width: 5%;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.ListImage img {
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#slider-code .viewport {
    float: left;
    width:90%;
    height: 95px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#slider-code .buttons {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px 10px 0 10px;
    float: left;
}
#TickHead {
    margin-top: 3px;
}
#slider-code .prev {
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
#slider-code .next {
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
#slider-code .disable {
    visibility: hidden;
}
#slider-code .overview {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.TestingTickerText {
    vertical-align: top;
    color: #666666;
    font-family:'Open Sans', "lucida grande", tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
}
#slider-code .overview li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    padding: 1px;
    height: 65px;
    width: 105px;
    left: 0;
}
#slider-code .pager {
    overflow:hidden;
    list-style: none;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 0 0 45px;
}
#slider-code .pager li {
    float: left;
}
#slider-code .pagenum {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
    color: #555555;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
}
#slider-code .active {
    color: #fff;
}
```

The php

```
<div id="slider-code">
    <div class="PrevArrow">
        <a href="#" class="prev"><img src="Link to Left Arrow"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="viewport">
        <ul class="overview">
             <li>Item 1</li>
             <li>Item 2</li>
             <li>Item 3</li>
             etc...
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="NextArrow">
        <a href="#" class="next"><img src="Link to Right Arrow"/></a>
    </div>';
<center>
        <span id="TickHead" class="cat_bg2">Games Currently Testing or Releasing</span>
    </center>
</div>
```

The jQuery

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function(){               
        $('#slider-code').tinycarousel({ display: 1});
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're having is due to css positioning of the images. Try adjusting the margins so that they will be placed slightly further away from each other; so that when no image is appended the slider will stop and there will be no space. If thats not the issue, try   this:

1: 
Create a div and place all of the slider images in it.

2:
Give each arrow button a separate div and class.

3:
Use the jquery append function to dynamically add images to the slider class when a user clicks either button.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.arrowbutton').click(function(){
        $('.imageslider').append('.image');
    });
});
```

Also, remember to give your image slider a set width in css, and set overflow to hidden. That should make sure no appended images go outside of the slider, and no scrollbars appear.